# What is the format and algorithm that my old project is using for hashing password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, encryption, hash, asp.net-core-3.1

**Normal String**

> Passw0rd

**Hashed by MVC project**

> 4mLjm+Nu1e5MUMsW03dwMw2vm80=

I think the old project is using MVC4. And I am trying to hash the password from ASP.NET core 3.1. Two project are pointing to the same database, so I want to make sure that asp.net core 3.1 password hasher generate the same password like hashed password above.

Is there any way to make this hashed password from asp.net core3.1 ? to verifypassword?

Comment: You don’t have access to the method that does this hashing? If you do, please provide the class and method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default Hashing Algorithm Is HMACSHA256 . However you would need to confirm that looking at your code and config. Check here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#default-hashing-algorithm-is-now-hmacsha256

Once confirm you can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation to do the same:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-3.1